# Azure app (blob storage) run only on localhost

Tags: php, azure, localhost, blob

I am trying to run an azure app which use blob storage.
I tried with the following sample kit:
https://github.com/Interop-Bridges/Windows-Azure-Sample-Kit-4-PHP/tree/master/GuestBookUsingBlobs
*(I changed the storage account and key in index.php)*

So my problem is that after I deploy this to azure I get 500 internal server error, however on localhost it works fine!

Whats wrong?
Thank you!

*(a simple phpinfo() file works fine in azure too)*

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

above the changed web.config

I do the deploying with this: http://rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2011/04/18/How-To-Do-PHP-Deployment-To-Windows-Azure.aspx

Comment: You should take a look at the official PHP on Windows Azure tutorials put out by Microsoft. They show how to setup the SDK, run through sample projects, and how to deploy your app.

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided above I guess:

1. You have a sample web page (xyz.php) which just have phpinfo() and it does works fine. Which indicate that your role does have PHP configured correctly.
2. However the index.php which have the code which directly connect with your Azure Blob Storage does not work correctly.

To start investigation, i would say 500 Internal Server Error is a very generic error and you would have slim chance to investigate using this error. Here are couple of things to check in your code:

- Are you using absolute path or relative path in your code? Please check index.php and where the form action is being submitted please verify that you do have proper relative path because on Azure VM, absolute path will not work
- Have your enabled PHP error display using display_errors=On in PHP.ini
- Please use this link to add custom error message in your code [How to view actual error on Azure fastCGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829996/how-to-view-actual-error-on-azure-fastcgi)
- IF you have ability to RDP to your Azure VM please log in and debug the PHP code directly on Azure VM instance
- Finally IF you need assistance in RCA for your problem, please contact Azure Support team (24x7 via web or phone) at the link below and they will have ability to access your instance (with your permission) and provide you root cause.

https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=14928&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

When contacting Azure Support, please provide your Subscription ID, Deployment ID, your Azure Live Account ID and a small description of your problem.

Comment: yes it has: relative path;  display_errors=On; Now I changed the web.config and now there is no 500 internal error but only a white page after press the submit button...

Comment: I am not sure how much code you have changed in  index.php because the initial HTML should be visible if your page is loaded properly with the form so u can add entries in the guest book. May i ask what you have changed in web.config also can u provide web.config?

Comment: I just checked the same code with my instance and it does works fine with my Azure storage credentials so i think it could be related with your code itself. Your best best is the have RDP enabled and log into your instance and root cause this issue.

Comment: I added my web.config file to the forst post and added a link which show how I try to deploy my app

Comment: I see the problem now. I just checked the link which you are using and I would say that the info you are using is very old and may not work correctly. As the current Azure SDK is 1.6, I would suggest using supported PHP Solution in Windows Azure provided by Windows Azure Interoperability team as below which I have tested to work fine without any problem: http://phpazure.codeplex.com/releases/view/78020